# How to find last row that has same value as my last one and output the number of that row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with stock transactions, so in column C I will input the name of the stock that I'm buying or selling at a given time.

.....A.....|....B....|...C....|

DATE  | TYPE   |  STOCK

...........|    Buy |     IBM

...........|    Sell |   Apple

...........|    Buy    |   Google

...........|    Buy |     IBM

How can I get the number of the row where the stock im trading now was last mentioned?

i.e. when I last put IBM on row 5, how can i get next to it an output of 2 which is the row of my last IBM input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D2** enter the **Array** formula:

```
=IF(MAX(IF($C$1:C1=C2,ROW($C$1:C1)))=0,"",MAX(IF($C$1:C1=C2,ROW($C$1:C1))))
```

and copy down
[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Wow that was super fast! thank you so much for taking the time to share your knowledge.